# My code doesn't work as expected when I don't define a new variable to store the sum of two integers

Tags: c

I'd like to take two integers from the user and print the results of this equation:

`result = ((num1 + num2) * 3) – 10`

When I declare `num1` , `num2` and `result` as integer variables the program didn't run, there was an error.

```
int num1 ,num2, result ;
printf("please enter the first number:");
scanf("%d",&num1);
printf("please enter the second number:");
scanf("%d",&num2);
result = (((num1 + num2) * 3) – 10 );
printf("the result is %d",result);
```

But when I defined a new variable `y` to be equal the sum of `num1` and `num2` the program works successfully:

```
int num1 ,num2, result,y ;
printf("please enter the first number:");
scanf("%d",&num1);
printf("please enter the second number:");
scanf("%d",&num2);
y=num1+num2;
result = ((y * 3) – 10 );
printf("the result is %d",result);
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: "the program didn't run where there was error". What was the actual error?

Comment: and what exactly did you input as num1 and num2 in each case?

Comment: Make sure you end the print statement with `\n`.

Comment: And what was the output for the given input in each case?

Comment: Note that the character you used for `-` (as caught with copy/paste) is not the expected one (ASCII code 45).

Comment: You have to turn warnings of your compiler on.It would have told you. (And as this is actually an error. it will have told you there was something wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

It does run.

In the line:

```
result = (((num1 + num2) * 3) - 10 );
```

your `-` is an horizontal bar character, delete it and replace with the propper minus.

Look here https://repl.it/@anastaciu/BlondSuperbTrigger

Comment: thank you it works successfully